# How to work with synchronous trove collection?

Tags: java, web-applications, collections, thread-safety, trove4j

I'm writing dynamic web project in Java and tried using Trove Collection in one of my servlets.
I saw that the problem occurs in the collection create line and after that my project stacks.
I've found that the Trove collections are not thread-safe (and maybe that's the problem in web project server side) but even when I tried this line:

```
 TIntObjectMap m = TCollections.synchronizedMap( new TIntObjectHashMap());
```

the project couldn't pass the line (by the way, in regular java project this line worked).

Can I use Trove collection in web project server side at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but as you noted, the collections are not thread safe. However, I don't see why the code you referenced would work standalone but not in a servlet. Can you post the code and the error you get ?